# Какой doctype надо поставить, чтобы работал javascript?

Tags: javascript, doctype

Есть код:

```
var d = document.body;
    c = (d.scrollTop*2 + d.clientHeight)/2;
```

Он работает и считает верно, если убрать doctype.
Но если его убрать - ползет верстка.
Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<doctype xhtml> - все работает

Answer (score 0):

работоспособность `JavaScript` не зависит от тега `<DOCTYPE>`

В вашем же случае все данные стоит привести сначала к числовому виду. И если вы применяете какой-то стиль, указывающий размер, то добавляйте единицы измерения (пиксели, проценты и т.п.).